# Chrome is crashing in AWS windows server 2019 while running selenium test cases

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, aws-codebuild

> I have created a selenium project using the cucumber framework.  I have feature files, TestRunner, and Testbase class in test/java file. While code is running locally and testcases are getting generated. But the same if I want to run it on AWS codebuild it is getting error `org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.`

To resolve it I have tried using maven directly from the pom.xml file and using `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup()` it to setup the chrome driver, Additionally set the chrome binary i.e. the chrome.exe file path.

**buildspec.yml**

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto17
    commands:
      - echo "Install dependencies"
      - choco install -y googlechrome 
      - choco install -y chromedriver 
      - choco install -y maven
      - choco install -y nodejs-lts
      - npm install -g selenium-webdriver
      - npm install -g cucumberVersion /value
      - chromeDriver -v
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - dir 
      - echo "Compile source code"
      - mvn clean 
      - mvn install
  build:
commands:
      - echo "Run tests"
      - mvn test
```

**TestBeseClass.Java**

```
package Util;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class TestBaseClass {    
        public static WebDriver driver;
        public static Properties prop;
        
        public TestBaseClass() {
            
            try {
                prop = new Properties();
                FileInputStream fls = new FileInputStream("src\\test\\java\\Config\\config.properties");
                prop.load(fls);     
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        
        }
        
        public static void initializationWithKey(String KeyOfURL) {
            String sbrowser = prop.getProperty("browser");
            String sUrl = prop.getProperty(KeyOfURL);
            if(sbrowser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\chromedriver\\tools\\chromedriver.exe");
                // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src\\test\\resources\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
                // this code is  added to fix the chrome browser issue
                ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
                co.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
                // co.addArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
                // co.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
                co.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
                co.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver(co);
            
            }else if(sbrowser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src\\test\\resources\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
                // System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get(sUrl);
        }
        

        
        public static void closeBrowser() {
            driver.quit();
            
        }


    }
```

[Actual error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ReAN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have resolved the above issue by using Linux based image on codebuild.

While running on linux faced issue of `org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:  Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)`

made changes in TestBaseClass.java

```
public static void initializationWithKey(String KeyOfURL) {
    String sbrowser = prop.getProperty("browser");
    String sUrl = prop.getProperty(KeyOfURL);
    if (sbrowser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
    
        // this code is added to fix the chrome browser issue
        ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
        // co.setBinary(sUrl);
        co.addArguments("--headless");
        co.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        co.addArguments("--window-size=1024,768");
        co.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
        co.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
        driver = new ChromeDriver(co);
    } 
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(sUrl);
}
```

changes made:

- Running code in headless mode
- giving correct path chromedriver where it is getting installed on image